# Loading a qgsproject when another one is loaded

Tags: pyqgis, qgs

I am loading a project with:

```
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo(path))
```

When i try to load another project it subtracts the layers and shows nothing. But if I try doing it again it works.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.10

Comment: Can't seem to replicate your issue. I tested it on QGIS 2.6.1, 2.8.2, 2.10.1 and 2.12.0 for Windows, all of which loads the project immediately. Are you also using Windows? Could you test it on another QGIS version?

Comment: QgsProject.instance().clear()
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo("~/project1.qgs"))
QgsProject.instance().read(QFileInfo("~/project2.qgs"))                                 project1 has 2 layers. project2 also has these 2 layers plus another layer. When executed canvas shows only one layer that was not in project1.

Comment: Perhaps you neet to call `iface.newProject()` before reading a new project.